# iOS5 Twitter api get details about all followers in a single request?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, twitter

I'm new to the Twitter API, but has used the Facebook API several times. In the Facebook API it's possible to get a list of all the current user's friends containing their names, Thumb Url, Facebook Id etc.

I can't seem to find a similar method in the Twitter API.

I can get a list of all the current users, friend's ids (up to 5000) using:

https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?adc=phone&cursor=-1&id=myuser&stringify_ids=true

and then look them up (up to 100 at a time ) to get the details, but it seems overly complicated and time consuming, for a pretty trivial task.

Is it really the way to do it? - any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using two calls. There seems to be a single call to get all followers and a few details about them, but this call is considered obsolete and will be removed fall 2012.